# Beamer template for thesis presentation

Tags: beamer

I am planning to submit my Ph.D. thesis shortly (and thanks to this site and in particular to all those who have helped on my latex). I have considered using the beamer-torino template https://blog.barisione.org/2007/09/18/torino-a-pretty-theme-for-latex-beamer/ for my thesis seminar presentation.

I was hoping someone would know a better template for my use. Thanks in advance!

**Edits:** I tried with this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-presentation-template-beamer-english-version-dpt-of-computer-engineering-technological-educational-institute-of-peloponnese/vwhtyshhtqmg.

The codes of the above template: **1st tex file** --

> \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
> \ProvidesPackage{TeiPel_En_Beamer_Layout}[22/06/2017 TeiPel Beamer Layout Package (English version)]
> \usepackage{xstring}
> \usepackage{calculator}
> \usepackage{ragged2e}
> \edef\teilogoeps{gu-logo.JPG}
> \edef\teilogopng{GUlogo.png}
> \newcommand{\setTeipelLayout}[1]{
> > \usetheme{Antibes}
> \IfSubStr{#1}{newlogo}%
> > {%
> > \definecolor{teipel_red}{RGB}{85, 85, 57}
> > \edef\teilogoeps{teipel_new_logo.eps}
> > \edef\teilogopng{teipel_new_logo.eps}
> > }%
> > {%
> > \definecolor{teipel_red}{RGB}{190,65,65}
> > \edef\teilogoeps{gu-logo.JPG}
> > \edef\teilogopng{GUlogo.png}
> > }
> > % set colors
> > \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
> > \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=teipel_red!10}
> > \setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=white, fg=red}
> > \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=orange!40}
> > \setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=teipel_red!60!black, bg=gray!30}
> > \setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=white, bg=red}
> > \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=teipel_red}
> > \setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=teipel_red!70!black,fg=white}
> > \setbeamercolor{fine separation line}{}
> > \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
> > \setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white}
> > \setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=teipel_red!60,fg=teipel_red!60!black}
> > \setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
> > \setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
> > \setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
> > \setbeamercolor{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
> > \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=brown}
> > \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=gray}
> > \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=normal text.fg, bg=normal text.bg}
> > \setbeamercolor{separation line}{}
> > \setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=red}
> > \setbeamercolor{sidebar}{parent=palette primary}
> > \setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=teipel_red, fg=teipel_red}
> > \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=brown}
> > \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg=gray}
> > \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=normal text.fg, bg=normal text.bg}
> > \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
> > \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=brown}
> > \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=teipel_red}
> > %\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
> > %\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
> > \setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=teipel_red}
> > \setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
> > % remove beamer's navigation bar
> > \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
> > % Comment to completely cover next transparencies %%
> > \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
> > % Table of contents before each Section
> > \AtBeginSubsection[]{
> >  \frame{
> >    \frametitle{Contents}
> >    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
> >  }
> > }
> > % Add draft watermark
> > \IfSubStr{#1}{draft}%
> > {%
> > \usepackage{tikz}%
> > \setbeamertemplate{background}{%
> >   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
> >       \node[rotate=90, anchor=west, xshift=15pt, yshift=-10pt] at (current page.south west){\textcolor{gray!60}{\emph{Watermark}}};%
> > \end{tikzpicture}%
> > }%
> > }{}
> }
> \newcommand{\supervisor}[3]{
> > \subtitle{\textsc{A Thesis}}
> > \logo{\begin{tabular}{c}
> \includegraphics[height=0.7cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png} \
> \color{teipel_red}\scalebox{1.7}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
> \end{tabular}}
> > \institute{Department of Mathematics\ \textsc{University of X} \[5pt]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{logo}}\[5pt] \scalebox{0.9}{#1: #2, #3}}
> }
> \newcommand{\presentationDate}[1]{
> > \date{\tiny{#1}}
> }
> \newcommand{\typesetFrontSlides}{
> > \begin{frame}[plain]
> > \titlepage
> > \end{frame}
> > \begin{frame}[plain]{Contents}
> >  \tableofcontents
> > \end{frame}
> }

> % format multiple author names in title page
> \makeatletter
> > \long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
> > \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}%
> > \def\and{\beamer@andtitle}%
> > \noexpandarg\StrCount{#2}{\and}[\numberofauthorsminusone]%
> > \ADD{1}{\numberofauthorsminusone}{\numberofauthors}%
> > \DIVIDE{1}{\numberofauthors}{\columnwidthfactor}%
> > \renewcommand\and{\column{\columnwidthfactor\textwidth}\centering}%
> > \begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]%
> > \column{\columnwidthfactor\textwidth}\centering%
> > #2%
> > \end{columns}%
> > }%
> > \def\beamer@shortauthor{#1}%
> > \ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
> > \def\beamer@andstripped{}%
> > \beamer@stripands#1 \and\relax
> > {\let\inst=@gobble\let\thanks=@gobble%
> > \def\and{, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@andstripped}}}
> > \fi%
> }
> \makeatother
> \endinput

**2nd tex file** --

> \PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
> \PassOptionsToPackage{naturalnames}{hyperref}
> \documentclass{beamer}
> \usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
> \usepackage{color}
> \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
> \usepackage{epstopdf}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \graphicspath{{./images/}}
> \usepackage{TeiPel_En_Beamer_Layout}
> \setTeipelLayout{draft,newlogo}% options: "draft", "newlogo"
> \title[Short title]{Title}
> \author[F. Name]{Full Name}
> \supervisor{Supervisor}{Name}{Professor}
> \presentationDate{December 12, 2020}

> \begin{document}
> % typeset front slides
> > \typesetFrontSlides

> \section{Chapter 1: Introduction}
> \begin{frame}
> Some texts.
> \end{frame}
> \end{document}

But I found (after spending quite a while changing the logos, watermarks, etc.) that there is no definition/theorem numbering, which I prefer it to be there. I tried the suggestions given here [Theorem Numbering in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/theorem-numbering-in-beamer) but could not get the desired change. I even tried a `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` but failed to get the numbering in the theorems (and definitions etc.).

I like this template and would like to use this if someone help me sort out the Theorem/Definition numbering. Thanks!

Comment: Beamer is for presentations. Are you looking for a template for the viva/defence or for the thesis itself?

Comment: for the viva/defence

Comment: Without an example of your code we are not able to help you. Have a look to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45817/theorem-definition-lemma-problem-numbering

Comment: @SergioCavero I added the codes to the template I mentioned. I will be glad if you could find time to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Connecting related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/where-to-find-custom-beamer-themes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may like [metropolis](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) or [blackboard](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/blackboard-beamer-theme/gcqgjfnkdmqj) (see SamCarter's blackboard [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165087/38244)) or [power-point based themes](https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports/src/master/). Also have a peek at the [beamer theme matrix](https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) or [another beamer theme matrix](https://mpetroff.net/files/beamer-theme-matrix/). As
fellow Sergio Cavero said, this site is not suitable for this kind of open-ended/opinion-based question. If you have a specific question on styles, you can ask it here.

Comment: @markhaokip Also, good luck for your PhD. I would encourage you to make the source code for your thesis/presentation public (not with the actual material, just as a template).

Comment: Thanks. This will get me going!

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I think that the question is too open and is out of context for this forum.

Secondly, have you not been given a rule of style and form of presentation from your doctoral school?

Thirdly, visit this website: [Overleaf templates](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/presentation), it would be useful for you. The best template is the one you feel most comfortable with.

Finally, good luck in this final step, I wish you the best.

Comment: well, thank you!