# Using cleveref for referencing amsthm objects in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, amsthm

I am a beginner with amsthm, and I'm using cleveref for referencing the theorem s/definitions/lemmas. BTW, all of this is happening in beamer. On using \Cref{label} for definitions, lemmas, and everything else under the sun - I get something of the form **Theorem <number>**. Everything isn't a theorem! I want **Definition <number>** and **Lemma <number>** too. How can I fix this?

I also get this error:

> Warning: hyperref package loaded with implicit=false option - disabling cleveref's hyperref support. This situation is not supported by cleveref, and there's no guarantee anything will work. You're on your own! on input line 2370.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\begin{definition}[Program]
\label{prog}
A program is a set of states in a labeled transition system.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Euler is the best mathematician.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
\label{xyz}
beamer is amazing.
\end{lemma}

We just saw \Cref{xyz} and \Cref{prog}.
```

Comment: Note that amsthm might not be compatible with beamer as it uses a very different theorem setup. Please also complete your example

Comment: Completed the example. @daleif How do I get around this, then?

Comment: Did you try just googling `latex beamer theorem numbering`? Here's the first hit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188393/3929, I'm pretty sure it is also mentioned in the beamer manual (not at pc so cannot test)

Comment: @daleif I have figured something out and edited the question, since now I have a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, beamer defines the definition to share a counter with the theorem like this:

```
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\translate{Definition}}
```

If you want cleveref to distinguish between both environments, you can redefine it without the shared counter:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\let\definition\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\let\lemma\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}[Program]
\label{prog}
A program is a set of states in a labeled transition system.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Euler is the best mathematician.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
\label{xyz}
beamer is amazing.
\end{lemma}

We just saw \Cref{xyz} and \Cref{prog}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But, but, ... There's no "Theorem 2", and it's `lemma` that has `\label{xyz}`.  There's more going wrong here.  Also, the code is silent regarding use of `amsthm` so it's unclear whether it's being used; I'll assume it isn't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just updated the answer to also redefine the lemma. I thought if I showed how to do the definition, the user could use the same technique to do the lemma themselves. Beamer will automatically load `amsthm`.

Comment: The first comment by @daleif above suggests that `beamer` and `amsthm` may be incompatible.  Never having tried to use them together, I punted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton We'd have a very big problem if `amsthm` wouldn't be compatible with beamer https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/865a19d4ec64f4c8e4935c19e162b8f4fd5aa190/base/beamerbasetheorems.sty#L18 :)